# Menu Bar similar to Ribbon

Tags: delphi, user-interface, menubar

Is there a Menu system  for Delphi applications, similar to the “Ms Ribbon”, where I can place different icon sizes, active and passive information, and is manageable both be the developer and customizable by the user ?

I currently use the DevExpress Menu Bar.
I am considering the Ribbon menu approach, though I don’t understand the legal issues around this one.

My current application as several Icons that can be placed in the Menu.
I like to allow different ICO sizes depending on several application issues, ICOs that can change size.
Be able to place a Big Logo, like the Windows Start Button at the Top Left.
And several Active components, the show both information, Color, etc depending on the application, data and status
Also allow user to customize, what he wants to see.

What do you recommend?

Comment: I prefer Alphaskins to DevExpress components, since the alphaskins are very easy to use and integrate into a Delphi project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You could use a ribbon](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Creating_an_Application_that_Uses_Ribbon_Controls).  That's pretty similar to a ribbon :)

[DevExpress has one](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExBars/Ribbon.xml) too, so you could add that to your existing DevExpress menus.

Marjan pointed out in a comment that [TMS Software have a ribbon component](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/advtoolbar.asp) as well.

I might misunderstand, since this seems too simple an answer.  You say you want something similar to the MS ribbon.  What do you want that's *different?*  Will a ribbon control do?

Comment: I am looking to an alternative to the "normal" menu system and to the Ribbon. But Yes What I am looking for is something like the Ribbon.

Comment: Well, there are at least two different ribbon controls for Delphi... I'd start with those, and maybe modify them if you want slightly different behaviour.  I've heard that DevExpress's ribbon is better than the inbuilt VCL one, so maybe start with that!

Comment: There is also the Ribbon menu by TMS Software ( tmssoftware.com )

Comment: Thanks @MarjanVenema.  I've added a link in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I correctly understand all your requirements, but Synopse has a [menu system](http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=280) that's similar to MS ribbons but not a total lookalike:
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to use Alphaskin's ribbon control.

http://www.alphaskins.com/

[image]